# Cannot Successfully Checkout SVN Repo

Tags: svn, repository

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Subversion error: Repository moved permanently to please relocate](https://serverfault.com/questions/128242/subversion-error-repository-moved-permanently-to-please-relocate)

I cannot check out my SVN repository. I think I have my config file written correctly:

```
# <!-- Begin SVN Config -->
    <VirtualHost *:80>
        Alias svn /
        ServerName svn.sachemsoftworks.com
        DocumentRoot /svn/
        ServerAdmin webmaster@sachemsoftworks.com
        <Location /svn>
            DAV svn
            SVNParentPath /svn/
            AuthType Basic
            AuthName "Sachem Softworks Projects"
            AuthUserFile /svn/.dav_svn.passwd
            Require valid-user
        </Location>
    </VirtualHost>
# <!-- /End SVN Config -->
```

Is there anything wrong with this config? The exact error I get when performing a checkout is:

> svn: Repository moved permanently to 'http://svn.sachemsoftworks.com/blackoutMgr/'; please relocate

I don't really understand what the problem is but if I try to browse the repository in a browser it works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What URL are you trying to use to check out?

You don't want that `Alias` directive, remove that; if you want to not use `/svn/reponame` as your path then change your `<Location /svn>` to just `<Location />`.

Move your `DocumentRoot` to point to some empty directory somewhere that's not going to fight with the SVN module's handler too, as discussed in the question that quanta linked, and that should cover it.