# Subversion error: Repository moved permanently to XY; please relocate

Tags: apache-2.2, svn

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Subversion error: Repository moved permanently to please relocate](https://serverfault.com/questions/128242/subversion-error-repository-moved-permanently-to-please-relocate)

I have some trouble with my own subversion server. At web view there is no problem but if anyone wants to checkout via client he gets the following message:

> svn: Repository moved permanently to 'XYZ'; please relocate

The shown 'new' location (XYZ) is the exactly same I submit in parameters.

My setup:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/htdocs/svn
        <Directory /var/www/htdocs/svn/>
                Options SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>
        <Location /repos/>
                DAV svn
                SVNParentPath /var/www/htdocs/svn/repos
                SVNListParentPath On
                SVNAutoversioning On
                SVNIndexXSLT /svnindex.xsl
                SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
                AuthzSVNAccessFile /var/www/config/svn.authz
                AuthType Basic
                AuthName "Subversion Repository"
                AuthUserFile /var/www/config/svn.passwd
                Require valid-user
                ModMimeUsePathInfo On
        </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

**Again**: I can watch/download my repos/files via webservice but can't checkout via client.

Comment: Hi Shane, it seems so. My fault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `/var/www/htdocs/` is the document root of Apache. If so, it is the reason for this behavior because Apache don't know whether to serve the physical path, or pass the request to the `mod_dav_svn`. The solution is move the root svn to the outside of Apache's document root, for e.g:

```
<Location /repos/>
    DAV svn
    SVNParentPath /home/svn/repos
    ...
</Location>
```

Comment: Thanks quanta, I changed the DocumentRoot to /var/www/htdocs/svn/public (and public files) and it work now.